# How to detect image is portrait and landscape mode about imageView zoom

Tags: ios, swift, image, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I am practicing how to use the imageView in Swift.

I recently try to do image zooming in `UIScrollView`, but my problem is that I don't know how to check the portrait and landscape image size.
Portrait image in my `ImageView` will look strange.

What am I doing wrong and how can I set different imageView size in a scrollView?

When I set constrain in imageView, the imageview will can't zoom. This is my code:

```
class imageViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    var url:String = ""
    var id:String = ""

    var scrollView:UIScrollView = UIScrollView()
    var imageView:UIImageView = UIImageView()

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.height*0.2248, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height:UIScreen.main.bounds.height*0.3748))

        imageFromUrl(imageView: imageView, url: url, id: id,isResize: false)

        scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.size.width, height: view.frame.size.height))
        scrollView.contentSize.width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
        scrollView.contentSize.height = UIScreen.main.bounds.height*0.3748
        scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1
        scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 5
        scrollView.delegate = self
        scrollView.addSubview(imageView)
        view.addSubview(scrollView)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    // MARK: - UIScrollViewDelegate    
    func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
        return imageView
    }
}
```

[[portrait image like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yy6g0.png)]

Comment: Whenever you set : `imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit` and `autoresazing mask`  or would do `NSLayoutConstraint` with 0 offsets between top, bottom, leading and trailing - it will fit like on the picture.

Comment: I don't know what you mean. I also set imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit. But it looks no working.